# Changing order of props in input dialog (addon development)

Tags: python, add-on, properties, development

I'm creating addon that adds couple of objects to the scene and I need to control input arguments. Figured out that the best way for me (with almost zero experience with python but 25+ years in other languages, mostly object oriented) is to use existing templates. Two of them that are working perfectly are `Addon Add Object` and `Operator Mesh Add`.

I can easily define new properties by adding simple code like this

```
# my properties

scale: FloatProperty(
    name="Scale",
    description="some description",
    min=0.000001, max=1000,
    default=0.01,
)
clWidth: FloatProperty(
    name="Chain Link Width",
    description="some description",
    min=0.01, max=10000,
    default=12.7,
)
clCount: IntProperty(
    name="Chain Link Pairs",
    description="some description",
    min=20, max=1000,
    default=41,
)

# ... etc
```

What I'm getting in lower left corner of the screen is input box like this.

[image]

What's bugging me a lot are those props outside of red mark atop of dialog. Course, they are important but mostly I don't use them at all. Is there a way to switch their position and put them below my custom properties or somehow collapse them to minimize size of dialog?

I've seen some addons are using different dialogs (the way I like it) but can't figure out how to get different look.

This is an example

[image]

Even if there's a way to remove those transform props completely, will be fine because I'm rarely using them and mostly doing all transforms later directly on the scene.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before but can't find it. Please look `draw` method in the docs https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#custom-drawing. I think you also have the option to hide individual properties when defining them with the `options = {"HIDDEN"}` argument https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=bpy%20props%20floatproperty#bpy.props.FloatProperty

Comment: @Gorgious I've been looking for answer here and around the web but couldn't find anything that I can use to solve it, even a hint. Problem is that those properties are not defined by me so I can't find a way to hide them. Guess they are defined in parent class somewhere else and inherited here. Thanx anyway, I'll take another look in official docs to see if there's something usable.

Comment: If you use the `draw`  method you'll be able to "whitelist" the props you want to display, any prop not specifically part of the draw method will not be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `options = {"HIDDEN"}` to prevent props from being displayed in the default operator layout redo panel.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=bpy%20props%20floatproperty#bpy.props.FloatProperty

```
import bpy


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    hide_me: bpy.props.IntProperty(options={"HIDDEN"})
    show_me: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    show_me_too: bpy.props.IntProperty()


    def execute(self, context):
        print("done")
        return {'FINISHED'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
```

[image]

Alternatively you can "whitelist" props to be displayed and choose how they will be displayed in the `draw` method. By default the `draw` method will display all props that do not have the `"HIDDEN"` option.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#custom-drawing

```
import bpy


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    hide_me: bpy.props.IntProperty(options={"HIDDEN"})
    hide_me_too: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    show_me: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    show_me_too: bpy.props.IntProperty()


    def execute(self, context):
        print("done")
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(self, "show_me", text="SHOW ME !!")
        row.prop(self, "show_me_too", text="SHOW ME TOO !!")
        self.layout.prop(self, "show_me", text="or show me like that")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanx a million mate.

Comment: Happy to help ! Cheers